# Spring MVC, pass button value from jsp to controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

We are creating a web app using Spring MVC.
We have three buttons, with id's 0, 1 and 2. We need to pass these id's to the controller. So that the value can be used in an external query. It is currently returning an error saying it cannot be found

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create2", method = RequestMethod.GET, param="0")
public String insertD(@ModelAttribute Create create){
if(create != null)  
    createService.insertD(create);
return "/slide";
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you have 3 buttons and you want to have 3 different actions when you click on each. If so than you should try to refer to them by name not an Id like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create2", method = RequestMethod.GET, param="typeNameOfYourButtonHere")
public String insertD(@ModelAttribute Create create){
if(create != null)  
    createService.insertD(create);
return "/slide";
}
```